# Yii Relational Query with 'through'

Tags: database, yii

Good evening,

In this page (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-with-through) **it's described how to get all comments** for all users of a particular group using 'through':
[image]

```
class Group extends CActiveRecord
{
    ...
    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'roles'=>array(self::HAS_MANY,'Role','group_id'),
            'users'=>array(
                self::HAS_MANY,'User',array('user_id'=>'id'),'through'=>'roles'
            ),
            'comments'=>array(
                self::HAS_MANY,'Comment',array('id'=>'user_id'),'through'=>'users'
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

**How can I do exactly the opposite? That is, get the group of the user who made a particular comment (Comment Model basically).**

So far, I'm not even able to reach 'role' table:

```
'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
'roles'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Role', array('id'=>'user_id'), 'through' => 'user') // shouldn't it join User.id to Role.user_id ?
```

It's raising the following error: 'Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user.user_id' in 'where clause'. And it seems related to the first line, not the second...

Any ideas?

Sincerely,
Apidcloud

Comment: May be try to switch it `array('user_id' => 'id')` ?

Comment: Please mention your model structure , their fields and their foreign key relation.

Comment: @SiZE that doesn't work

Comment: @AnamikaShrivastava the model structure and their fields are shown in the link

Comment: @Apidcloud do you create foreign keys?

Comment: @SiZE Yes, the foreign keys are set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to get the  group of the user who made a particular comment. You have to add these relation in the comment model.

```
    public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
        'roles'=>array(
            self::HAS_ONE,'Role',array('id'=>'user_id'),'through'=>'user'
            ),
            'group'=>array(
                self::BELONGS_TO,'Group','group_id','through'=>'roles'
            )
    );
}
```

And view file you can get group name like this.

```
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->group->name); ?>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It's raising this error:
The property "CBelongsToRelation.through" is not defined.

If I remove the 'group' array, it stills raises the error described in the main post.

Comment: It seems that the last array should be self::HAS_ONE instead, but it still raises the error described in the main post: 'Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user.user_id'

Comment: we can discuss your issue here, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102507/yii-help

Comment: it is working example i need to know have you created all the relation like your above diagram, and please show your complete model , controller function and view file. I will try to help you.

Comment: I'll post the relations tomorrow morning. Thanks!

Comment: There you go Anamika: http://pastebin.com/LLwbAEpT 
I'm aware that the 'em_kit' table (similar to 'role' in the example) shouldn't have the primary key set like that, but it wasn't implemented by me and changing that would imply further changes across the entire website.

Comment: Also the original relations: http://pastebin.com/jzNycdsh

I'm trying to edit 'Inspecao Model' so I can access 'Kit' from there.

Comment: Okay. I have checked with your given model structure and it is working fine in my system. Relation will be for Inspecao model.. i am using is this.

public function relations()
 {
  return array(
   'unidade' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Unidade', 'unidade_id'),
   'emkit'=>array(            self::HAS_MANY,'EmKit',array('id'=>'unidade_id'),'through'=>'unidade'
            ),
            'kit'=>array(
                self::BELONGS_TO,'Kit','kit_id','through'=>'emkit'
            )

  );
 }
and view file code is this.

<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->kit->nserie); ?>

Comment: Weird.. It's still not working here: 'The property "CBelongsToRelation.through" is not defined.'

Comment: Could it be related with search function? Here's the entire model: http://pastebin.com/MQXcmSTH

Comment: I was able to get it working by removing the 'through' in 'emkit'. Also had to make 'kit' as self::HAS_ONE instead of BELONGS_TO. I think it's related to the fact em_kit doesn't have the foreign keys as primary key. Here's the working model: http://pastebin.com/u8Wtzt32
Would you help me fix the 'search' function? Thanks for your help